# Adding a point to shortest path

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, optimization, computational-complexity, hamiltonian-path

If there exists a set of `n` points in a 2D coordinate system and an `n`-dimensional vector `V` that describes the shortest path containing all the `n` points and a second set of `n+1` points is created containing all the `n` points from the first set and another, arbitrary, point, can vector `V` be used to reduce the number of steps required to find an `(n+1)`-dimensional vector `V'` describing the shortest path in the second set? More precisely, must the `V'` be evaluated independently of `V`?

Comment: $2n-$dimensional vector V?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, this is the problem of the travelling salesman. If $\exists$ some easy (polynomial time) shortcut from the $n$-points problem to the $(n+1)$-points problem, then $\exists$ a polynomial time algorithm for the general problem. !!!